# Shortform for xml tag

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd

Having following `XML` example:

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter>foo</Parameter>
    <Parameter>bar</Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

How to write the element `Parameter` in a shorthand form?

Comment: Not sure if I am getting it. Some like this: <Parameters>
    <Parameter value="foo" />
    <Parameter value="bar" />
</Parameters>. Unless you define an attribute you can't do it, that is, if you want to keep the foo and bar values.

Comment: Thank's for this. Thought this would be possible without an attribute

Comment: Nop, I don't see how you could do it without that, where would you stick the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<Parameters>
    <Parameter value="foo" />
    <Parameter value="bar" />
</Parameters>
```

Unless you define an attribute you can't do it, that is, if you want to keep the foo and bar values.